# AM Demodulation code error MatLAB

Tags: matlab, amplitude-modulation, demodulation

```
f_lo = 50e3;  % frequency of local oscillator

A_lo = 1;  % amplitude of local oscillator
y_lo = A_lo*sin(2*pi*f_lo*time');

y_demod = y_lo.*filt_received;

demod_sig_FD = fft(y_demod);  % calculate frequency domain of audio
demod_sig_FD_amp = abs(demod_sig_FD)/no_of_pnts;  % calculate the amplitude of frequency domain
demod_sig_FD_amp_adj = fftshift(demod_sig_FD_amp);  % adjust the frequency sides

figure;
semilogy(freq, filt_rec_sig_FD_amp_adj, 'b');
hold on;
semilogy(freq, demod_sig_FD_amp_adj, 'r');
xlim([10, freq_max]);
grid minor;
box on;
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
legend('Filtered Received', 'Demodulated');
title('Frequency Domain of Filtered Received and Demodulated Signals');
```

The error is "arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation."
How do I fix this?

Comment: I tried pasting the Matlab code from the question into MATLAB 2020a to try running it, but got ``Unrecognized function or variable 'time'``. From the looks of if, the code in the question is missing how the variable ``time`` is set. Please can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/695871/edit) the question to be a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). P.S. I edited the question to add a code block to make the Matlab code readable.

Comment: @ChesterGillon I'm using 2023b, I didn't have a problem with time.

Comment: OK, will install 2023b to try that.

Comment: @ChesterGillon thank you

Comment: I have tried a fresh install of MATLAB 2023b under Ubuntu without any additional toolboxes, and still get ``Unrecognized function or variable 'time'.`` when try and run the code. There is [time](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/calendarduration.time.html) inside the calendarDuration class, which requires a single argument. In the posted code there is just ``time'``. Can you confirm what provides ``time`` in your environment. E.g. what does ``which('time','-ALL')`` report.

Comment: @ChesterGillon it originates from my carrier signal code:

Comment: @ChesterGillon mod_ind = 1;   % AM modulation index

f_carrier = 550e3;  % frequency of carrier sine wave

A_carrier = std(audio)/mod_ind;  % amplitude of carrier sine wave
y_carrier = A_carrier*sin(2*pi*f_carrier*time');

carrier_FD = fft(y_carrier);  % calculate frequency domain of audio
carrier_FD_amp = abs(carrier_FD)/no_of_pnts;  % calculate the amplitude of frequency domain
carrier_FD_amp_adj = fftshift(carrier_FD_amp);  % adjust the frequency sides

Comment: @MattCG this is not a chat forum ... all information must be added to the question ... please use the `edit` button to update your question